# C++ (DevC++) Segmentation Fault on Run

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

For Some reason when i'm trying to run this programm, it stops working. I can understand there's something like Stack Overflow, But Seriously how can i run this code? is there any possible way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 30000
int getUniqueNumber(int *szTable,int szCounter);
bool checkDuplicate(int *szTable,int szCounter,int szDupl);



class Sort {
    private:

    public:
        int szTable[N];
        /*Sort() {
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
                this->szTable[i]=getUniqueNumber(this->szTable,i);
            }
        }*/
    //  int bubbleSort();
    //  void quickSort();
    //  int straightSelSort();
    //  int straightInsSort();


};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Sort Tables[20];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sort Tables[20];` most probably exceeds your available stack size with `N = 30000`.

You may try to allocate an appropriate vector from the heap instead:

```
std::vector<Sort> Tables(20);
```